# Why do a lot of people recommend Vanguard so often?

Tags: mutual-funds, brokerage

What is it with Vanguard? I've heard the name come up a bunch, but I don't know why this particular company is getting all the good free press...

Comment: Tell you the truth. I do not find lots of Mutual Funds option with Vanguard.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Wikipedia says it best](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vanguard_Group):

> Vanguard is unusual among mutual-fund
>   companies since it is owned by the
>   funds themselves. In this structure,
>   each fund contributes a set amount of
>   capital towards shared management,
>   marketing, and distribution services.

In other words, the company is owned entirely by the shareholders of the funds in the company. The result is that Vanguard usually has the lowest cost index funds.

Comment: The lowest cost is a big part of it.

Comment: The low costs are nice, but what I like best is that this structure keeps interests of the unitholders and fund company **aligned**.  That's the *reason* for the low costs.

Comment: And if a 1% fee from the other guy doesn't sound like a lot, consider that your returns are probably around 4-8% (depending on how aggressive you are with your portfolio). That's up to a quarter of your returns. It's hard to earn that back consistently in another type of fund.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I'm confused about this. Does this structure mean that because each firm contributes a set amount of capital to running the company, they only expense ratio they need to charge is what's required to run the fund, and nothing more (so the company isn't trying to make a profit; just break even). I guess I don't see why this aligns the incentives. If Vanguard decides to charge higher expense ratios, investors (you, me, pension funds, whatever) pay the higher expense ratio, and the company earns more money. Am I missing something in the incentive structure?

Comment: @BenK Re: *"If Vanguard decides to charge higher [fees] [...] the company earns more money."* Yes, investors would pay higher fees; Vanguard the company would show a profit; **but** the company that profits is owned by its funds! *"The Vanguard Group is owned by Vanguard’s U.S.-domiciled funds and ETFs."* The profit would benefit the Vanguard *funds* that own Vanguard *the company*, and by extension the holders of units of those funds (you, me, pension funds, whatever.) Think of Vanguard the company as like any other ETF holding, except not publicly traded, and only held by Vanguard funds.

Comment: @BenK So, I hope I've demonstrated one need not worry about Vanguard the company *profiting* from higher fees when investing in their funds. However, as an exercise, I suggest you look up ["agency costs"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agency_cost). i.e. Vanguard *management* could, in theory, still benefit from higher fee revenue, not by creating a *profit*, but by using artificially higher fees to cover higher-than-justified expenses. Imagine a bunch of executives raising costs just to give themselves a big bonus or a outsized salary. One would hope corporate governance is good, too.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Ok that makes sense. The separation between the agency cost and the other costs of fees makes a lot of sense. That's a lot clearer to me now!

Answer (score 16):

I'll rain on the parade because I'm a cynical jerk. :)

Vanguard is at top of mind because they were the first provider of index funds and they spend a TON of money on advertising and public relations to establish themselves as THE provider of inexpensive investments. John Bogle is probably the only mutual fund founder that has held semi-celebrity status for decades... he's like the Steve Jobs of index funds.

That said, they also happen to be a company that is good at what it does.

Comment: Fair enough, but several Charles Schwab advisors feel it's OK to phone me at home, spam me, send me huge portfolio ads by mail, etc.  they call it "personalized services".  Plus, I don't see Vanguard with Super Bowl ads, while Schwab ads are common everywhere...

Answer (score 12):

Vanguard is where John Bogle started creating Index Funds.  When investors think of low cost index funds, Vanguard is typically the first to come to mind.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_fund):

> John Bogle graduated from Princeton
>   University in 1951, where his senior
>   thesis was titled: "Mutual Funds can
>   make no claims to superiority over the
>   Market Averages." Bogle wrote that his
>   inspiration for starting an index fund
>   came from three sources, all of which
>   confirmed his 1951 research: Paul
>   Samuelson's 1974 paper, "Challenge to
>   Judgment", Charles Ellis' 1975 study,
>   "The Loser's Game", and Al Ehrbar's
>   1975 Fortune magazine article on
>   indexing. Bogle founded The Vanguard
>   Group in 1974; it is now the largest
>   mutual fund company in the United
>   States as of 2009.

Also from the same quote, Vanguard is "now the largest mutual fund company in the United States as of 2009."

Being the biggest gives you a lot of name recognition.

Answer (score 10):

I've been a Vanguard client for more than 40 years. My reasons?  Wide selection of high quality funds; low costs; excellent service.  On the other hand, this is not a place for people who need advice.  At Vanguard, you are your own adviser.  They provide ample information, but the responsibility is yours.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I have to ask - if you're using index funds, how much management do you really need? Or did I misinterpret your answer?